# Proving lemma about centrality of idempotent elements in a Ring with no nilpotent elements.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, proof-explanation, idempotents

Reading the class notes I stumbled upon an unproved lemma that I am having issues proving.

The lemma is, if $R$ is a ring with no non-zero nilpotent elements and $e$ is idempotent then $e$ is central.

In other words, if $e$ is idempotent in such a ring, then $ex=xe$ for all $x\in R$.

I am however not sure how to actually prove the statement.

So far I have been playing around trying to find polynomials that can be factored into linear identical factors (e.g (x+e)^2) to see if I can make them be zero by converting an $e^k$ coefficient into $e$.

But something isn't fully clicking about this lemma.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider $a=ex-exe$ and $b=xe-exe$. Then $a^2=b^2=0$.

Since there are no nilpotent element, $ex-exe=xe-exe=0$ and thus $xe=ex$.

Comment: I appologize but it seems there is something missing:

$a^2 = (ex-exe)^2 = (ex-exe)(ex-exe)=exex-2exexe+exexe \neq 0$

Comment: @Makogan The ring isn't necessarily commutative.

Comment: We don't know that, but where am I using commutativity in my calculation?

Comment: @Makogan $(a-b)=a^2-ab-ba+b^2$ which is not $a^2-2ab+b^2$ unless $ab=ba$.

Comment: I see my error now, thank you very much